how do i get different map types on flutter
I am using fluttermaps to get the basic osm(open street map)layer to appear. it works but I am trying to add more options. Does anyone have any tips on where to go.
I have this so far and its working but I want different types of options on flutter map like you would using maps on iphone. Not using google maps

TileLayer get openStreetMapTileLayer => TileLayer (
      urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      userAgentPackageName: 'dev.fleaflet.flutter_map.example',
);


Have a look at: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

can you provide an example of it working with leaflet-providers. I am unable to get it working in my flutter project

you can use map controller and options for such additional features
FlutterMap(
    mapController: MapController(),
    options: const MapOptions(
      initialCenter: LatLng(42.58, 12.43),//like this
      initialZoom: 6,
    ),
    children: [],
);

doc:- https://docs.fleaflet.dev/

how would you select a certain type of map if wanted to use a specific one?

i think you can use diffrent url  in this urlTemplate: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',

Do you have any good providers that are easy to implement in flutter code

The answer was pretty simple. Hope this helps someone else. I read on fluttermaps docs that they accept tiles from everywhere even web servers. So all I had to do was copy the tile urls from my website over.
